# Consider the intergal $I = \int_{1}^{∞} e^{ax^2+bx+c}dx$ decide in each case whether the integral $I$ converges.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> **QUESTION:** Consider the intergal $$I = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{ax^2+bx+c} dx$$where $a,b,c$ are constants. Some combinations of values for these constants are given below and you have to decide in each case whether the integral $I$ converges.
>
> $(A)$ $I$ converges for $a = −1, b = 10 ,c = 100$.
>
> $(B)$ $I$ converges for $a = 1, b = −10 ,c = −100$.
>
> $(C)$ $I$ converges for $a = 0, b = −1, c = 100$.
>
> $(D)$ $I$ converges for $a = 0,b = 0 ,c = −100$.

---

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone please explain how to do this?

Comment: Just in those options the expression in the power is bounded means at infinite expression in option a is tending to -infinite means whole expression is tending to zero it means it converges it exists as a finete value in case of d why is it wrong means even though the power is constant u are adding up to infinite terms means it diverges

Comment: @Namburu Karthik, I am so sorry.. I just edited the question, the integration runs from $1$ to $\infty$ and not the reverse..

Comment: Just a minus sign can’t effect the convergence

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. You know this isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. Please reread [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Comment: @gen-z ready to perish, it's okay.. you have power to do your thing. I do not have a say in this.. but if you have some time, you may check out my previous posts, and you will see my working.. I don't know how to get this in your head, but if I am new to a question which I am unable to do and do not find it anywhere, where in the world will I get any ideas from? Not everyone has got the privilege like you to employ expensive teachers for their education. Thank you for teaching me the **ethics**  of the site and closing down my question..

Comment: @Namburu Karthik, I got it. Thank you so much for the hint...

Comment: @Stranger Forever Your welcome

Comment: @StrangerForever I haven’t paid a teacher in the history of my life. I’ve funded my education by working hard to maintain exceptional grades and a full-ride scholarship. I made strategic choices about where I went to school. And I can assure you that it wasn’t easy. I was abused as a child and young teen for many years and have struggled with clinical anxiety since then. Don’t make this an issue of power and privilege; this is just about you making an attempt. Secondly, you’re not new here. Now, to answer your question: you could have Googled “integral exponential of polynomial” and done some…

Comment: …research on that. If it was a fruitless endeavour, you could explain to us why, and we could better help you.

Comment: @gen-z ready to perish, if I had so much time in my life, and so much financial assistance to reward me for sitting and spending my days in research and understanding alien stuff by employing whatever little I have, without anything stirring in my stomach, I wouldn't have waited to enlighten from you.. I don't wish to dig deeper into words.. this is a good place to learn although not all people have the same spirit.. but anyway, leave it here. You have done your job, and I don't have a single percent of any grudge against you. If you knew what life can be, you will see how lucky you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) we got $I = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+10x+100} dx$

It happens that $e^{-x^2+10x+100} \sim_\infty e^{-x^2}$ which converges (it's smaller than $e^{-x}$ which is easy to prove that converges).

(B) we got $I = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{x^2-10x-100} dx$

Then $e^{x^2-10x-100} \sim_\infty e^{x^2}$ which does not converge.

(C) we got $I = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x+100} dx$

This integral converges and you can calculate that it is equal to $e^{99}$

(D) is false as e^{-100} is a costant.